# Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence such that $x_{n+1} \geqslant x_n - \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $(x_n)$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence such that $x_{n+1} \geqslant  x_n - \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $(x_n)$ converges.

I know that if I can prove that $(x_n)$ is monotone, then by the monotone convergence theorem, $(x_n)$ would converge, but I don't know where to start to show that.
There was a suggestion saying that I should first prove that $x_n - \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ is monotonically increasing, but that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: What contradiction was that? Proving that $x_n - \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ is monotonically increasing seems the best way to prove what you want

Comment: @Math_QED the series for $\ln(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$  is a bounded convergent sequence but it's not monotone, so your statement is false.

Comment: Sorry mixed up two things. Comment deleted.

Comment: @wilkersmon Well if I name $a_n = x_n - \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ then $a_{n+1} = x_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \geqslant x_n - \frac{1}{2^{n}} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = x_n - \frac{3}{2^{n+1}}$ but if I wanted to have $a_{n+1} \geqslant a_n$ then I would have $x_n - \frac{3}{2^{n+1}} \geqslant x_n - \frac{1}{2^{n}}$, but that implies that  $- \frac{3}{2^{n+1}} \geqslant - \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ which implies that $3 \leq 2$

Comment: Why would it converge?? If $x_{n+1}$ can be greater than $x_n$, then its enough to pick $x_0 = 1$ to see that you are going to have an infinite sum of 1's or more.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins:  there is no series here, just a sequence.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I stand corrected :). Since I have no clue about sequences, I'll just get going :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put
$$y_n:=x_n-{1\over 2^{n-1}}\leq\sup_k x_k=\xi<\infty\ .$$
Then
$$y_{n+1}=x_{n+1}-{1\over 2^n}\geq x_n-{2\over 2^n}=y_n\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
It follows that the $y_n$ form a bounded increasing sequence, hence converge to a real number $\eta$. This allows to conclude that
$$x_n=y_n+{1\over 2^{n-1}}\to\eta\qquad(n\to\infty)\ .$$